# Does Sencha Touch include a fix for the 300ms delay?

Tags: performance, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am curious to know if the 300ms delay for tap events has been fixed or is something which is configurable in Sencha Touch 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha touch has its own implementation and it has a 300ms delay because of doubletap. It is in defined in [maxDuration](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.event.recognizer.DoubleTap-cfg-maxDuration)

Also check out https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282102-Tap-vs-Click-300ms-delay

Disable doubleTap delay:

```
Ext.define("NoDelay", {
    override : "Ext.event.recognizer.DoubleTap",
    config: {
        maxDuration: 0
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I am not using double-tap interaction in the app, is there a configuration through which I can disable this ?